# HTML lists and z-index on content of li

Tags: html, css

I am trying to solve an issue. I have a regular list. Within the li's I have a overlapping div, witch appears on a hover. The problem is, that the hover is always overlapped by the next li. How can i make it happen, that the content of the next li stays below the hovered div. Html and css seems to stack li's? Is this a know problem?

I already tried z-index, but that will not work on child elements.

**Its impossible to add the complete code, but this basically shows it. Why is the next li-element always overlapping the last and how can I get around this?**

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 120%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li style="z-index:1;"><!-- list-element 1 -->
  <div style="z-index:4;"><img src="http://img.brothersoft.com/screenshots/softimage/f/free_cat_wallpaper-407575-1285474870.jpeg" style="width:100%;" /></div>
 </li>
 <li style="z-index:1;"><!-- list-element 2 -->
  <div style="z-index:4;"><img src="http://img.brothersoft.com/screenshots/softimage/f/free_cat_wallpaper-407575-1285474870.jpeg" style="width:100%;" /></div>
 </li>
 <li style="z-index:1;"><!-- list-element 3 -->
  <div style="z-index:4;"><img src="http://img.brothersoft.com/screenshots/softimage/f/free_cat_wallpaper-407575-1285474870.jpeg" style="width:100%;" /></div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code. It's impossible to answer your question without it.

Comment: Edited the post and added code, ty!

Comment: _"Why is the next li-element always overlapping the last"_ - because absolute positioning takes an element out of the normal flow, so that it does not influence the height of its parent any more. All of your LI elements are therefor only as high as a potential single line of text content would demand (so the result of font-size and line-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**/* EDIT: My Mistake - I misunderstood your question. */**

Do the positioning on the `.img-wrapper`. (code snippet updated below too)

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tqtveoau/4/

**/* END EDIT */**

I'm guessing this isn't your production code but always try and use classes for your styles.

```css
.list-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

.img-wrapper {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  width: 120%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.list-item:hover .img-wrapper {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="list-item">
 List Item
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="http://img.brothersoft.com/screenshots/softimage/f/free_cat_wallpaper-407575-1285474870.jpeg" style="width:100%;" />
   </div>
  </li>
 <li class="list-item">
 List Item
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="http://img.brothersoft.com/screenshots/softimage/f/free_cat_wallpaper-407575-1285474870.jpeg" style="width:100%;" />
   </div>
  </li>
   <li class="list-item">
   List Item
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="http://img.brothersoft.com/screenshots/softimage/f/free_cat_wallpaper-407575-1285474870.jpeg" style="width:100%;" />
   </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See the fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/tqtveoau/3/

Comment: Thank you. No its not my production code. It is simplified. Thanks your your demonstration. It exactly shows my dilemma. When hovering over the first li-element, the second li-element overlaps the hover image. But i found a solution. I added a z-index: 1; to the list-item and a z-index: 5; to the li:hover. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/b5Leqqf6/1/ Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Move the styles from your img to the parent div and give it a class. Also set the background of the div that's absolute to white